# Can i do a file based backup of a Windows 10 system partition on a UEFI system?

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, efi, bcdboot

I'm dualbooting Windows 10 and Linux Mint.

Is it possible to do a **file based backup** of the Windows System Partition using Linux?

UEFI is already entirely file based and not bound to the MBR of the disk.

[edit: the UEFI boot process is independ of the MBR. Thus im not in the need of backing up the MBR like it used to be when using BIOS systems.]

My question is whether the boot process after loading the bootloader from the EFI-partition is entirely file based too on the windows site.

The workflow would be the following for the backup (booting linux):

1. Back up the files of the EFI-Partition
2. Back up the files of the Windows Partition
3. Back up the files of the Recovery Partition

to restore the following needs no be done:

1. boot Linux live cd. start gparted.
2. create an empty fat partition. Set the correct flags.
3. copy the EFI files to that partition.
4. create a recovery Partition
5. copy the Recovery Files to that partition.
6. create an ntfs-Partition.
7. copy the windows files to that partition.
8. boot from windows usb recovery media
9. Fix the bootloader on the EFI-Partion using **bcdboot**
10. Repair windows recovery using **reagentc**

At least for the recovery and efi partition part I can tell that this works because I once deleted and restored it from files this way.

I already did the steps above copying partitions with gparted when moving the system to a new drive. The partitions got new UUIDs and new positions. With bcdboot/reagentc I could repair the EFI- and recovery partitions afterwards to boot successfully.

Will this work with file-copies, too? Is there something "inside a windows partition" that is not visible when observing the files on the drive.

I dont want to copy the whole partition because I want to do automated incremental backups with rsync on a btrfs disk. File based could save a lot of time there for me.

Comment: UEFI does not make sense in this context (it's not a disk partitioning schema).  I think you mean GPT, since you are comparing UEFI to MBR, that would make the most sense.

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to take an image backup of the whole disk, rather than jumping through so many hoops?

Comment: @harrymc I think OP's goal is to have a non-proprietary incremental backup solution. I haven't heard of a non-proprietary disk image format yet (sparse files would work I guess) and I'm not aware of any open source imaging tools that support incremental images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, but it won't work for you.**

NTFS permissions are essential for post-Vista Windows versions to work correctly and you can't preserve these on *NIX-like filesystems like btrfs. You need NTFS (maybe ReFS would work too, I'm not sure).

Good news is that Windows has a mechanism called [Shadow Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) which is ideal for incremental backup. A lot of backup solutions is based on it. I'm personally using Veeam Agent (it's free for basic use cases). Maybe you could do with [incremental DISM files](https://superuser.com/a/1404208/194694) too if you'd like to avoid 3rd-party solutions. Here's a [DISM megatutorial](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/194694).

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally forgot about NTFS permissions.